# How to Make Simple Snake Game in c# console?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do a basic snake game in c# console. But I it's not working as I want now. I'm trying to do the snake 5 * size but when I'm trying to do it something weird happening. It is working perfectly fine with 1 * size. But I'm trying to do it like when I press the s button it should go down and rest of the snakes body should be twisted as normal but in my snake game it's not twisting at all. I could only got that far.

```
using System;

namespace SnakeGame
{
    class App
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            char ch;
            int col = 38, row = 15;
            System.Console.CursorVisible = false;
            System.Console.SetCursorPosition(col, row);
            System.Console.Write("*");
            for (; ; )
            {
                ch = System.Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;
                System.Console.SetCursorPosition(col, row);
                System.Console.Write(" ");
                switch (ch)
                {
                    case 'a':
                        --col;
                        break;
                    case 'w':
                        --row;
                        break;
                    case 's':
                        ++row;
                        break;
                    case 'd':
                        ++col;
                        break;
                    case 'q':
                        goto EXIT;
                }
                System.Console.SetCursorPosition(col, row);
                System.Console.Write("*");
            }
        EXIT:
            System.Console.CursorVisible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see you storing any data besides the snake's head here... How would you expect it to display the rest of the body?

Comment: My first thought is to store the snake character positions (the body) in a list, and then don't erase the head as it moves - only erase the last character (the tail) when the list is the desired snake length.

Comment: FYI, typically people will do `while(true)` instead of `for(;;)`

Answer (score 1):

One idea for creating a snake with a body is to store the snake body positions in a list. We can use a `System.Drawing.Point` to store the `X` and `Y` coordinates of a body part, so the snake would be a `List<Point>`.

Then, as we're moving the snake, we do two things:

1. Draw the new head
2. If the snake length (`List.Count`) is too long, remove the last character from the tail.

For example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var snakeLength = 5;
    var snake = new List<Point> {new Point(38, 15)};

    Console.CursorVisible = false;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(snake.Last().Item1, snake.Last().Item2);
    Console.Write("*");

    while (true)
    {
        var ch = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
        if (ch == ConsoleKey.Q) break;

        var tail = snake.First();
        var head = snake.Last();

        if (snake.Count >= snakeLength)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(tail.X, tail.Y);
            Console.Write(' ');
            snake.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        switch (ch)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.A:
            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                snake.Add(new Point(head.X - 1, head.Y));
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.W:
            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                snake.Add(new Point(head.X, head.Y - 1));
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.S:
            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                snake.Add(new Point(head.X, head.Y + 1));
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.D:
            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                snake.Add(new Point(head.X + 1, head.Y));
                break;
        }

        head = snake.Last();

        Console.SetCursorPosition(head.X, head.Y);
        Console.Write("*");
    }

    Console.CursorVisible = true;
}
```

---

Now this seems to work ok, but it puts all the burdon of moving a snake in our Main method, which is both messy and not portable. To improve upon this, we could make a `Snake` class that knows how to draw and move a snake, and we can give it properties like `Length` and `Symbol` that can be set by the user of the class.

To further encapsulate our code, we might want to make a `SnakePart` class as well, which knows how to draw or erase a single character of the snake, and then we can have a collection of these `SnakePart` objects stored in our `Snake` class.

For example:

```
public class SnakePart
{
    public char Symbol { get; set; }
    public Point Position { get; set; }

    public SnakePart(Point position, char symbol)
    {
        Position = position;
        Symbol = symbol;
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Position.X, Position.Y);
        Console.Write(Symbol);
    }

    public void Erase()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Position.X, Position.Y);
        Console.Write(' ');
    }
}
```

Now we can create a snake from these parts:

```
public class Snake
{
    public enum Direction { Up, Down, Left, Right }

    public char Symbol { get; set; }

    private readonly SnakePart[] _body;
    private SnakePart Head => _body.First();
    private SnakePart Tail => _body.Last();

    public Snake(Point startingPoint, int length, char symbol = '*')
    {
        Symbol = symbol;

        // Initialize our array with all parts starting at the head position
        _body = Enumerable
            .Range(0, length)
            .Select(x => new SnakePart(startingPoint, symbol))
            .ToArray();
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        foreach (var snakePart in _body)
        {
            snakePart.Draw();
        }
    }

    public void Move(Direction direction)
    {
        // Create a new part that will be placed in the new head location
        SnakePart newHead = null;

        switch (direction)
        {
            case Direction.Up:
                newHead = new SnakePart(new Point(Head.Position.X, 
                    Head.Position.Y - 1), Symbol);
                break;
            case Direction.Down:
                newHead = new SnakePart(new Point(Head.Position.X, 
                    Head.Position.Y + 1), Symbol);
                break;
            case Direction.Left:
                newHead = new SnakePart(new Point(Head.Position.X - 1, 
                    Head.Position.Y), Symbol);
                break;
            case Direction.Right:
                newHead = new SnakePart(new Point(Head.Position.X + 1, 
                    Head.Position.Y), Symbol);
                break;
        }

        // Erase the tail, move all parts one index towards
        // the end of the array, add the new head and draw it
        Tail.Erase();
        for (var i = _body.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            _body[i] = _body[i - 1];
        }
        _body[0] = newHead;
        Draw();
    }
}
```

After this, our `Main` method code is a little cleaner and easier to read and maintain:

```
private static void Main()
{
    Console.CursorVisible = false;
    var snake = new Snake(new Point(Console.WindowWidth / 2, Console.WindowHeight / 2), 
        5, '*');

    snake.Draw();

    while (true)
    {
        var ch = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
        if (ch == ConsoleKey.Q) break;

        switch (ch)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.W:
            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                snake.Move(Snake.Direction.Up);
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.S:
            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                snake.Move(Snake.Direction.Down);
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.A:
            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                snake.Move(Snake.Direction.Left);
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.D:
            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                snake.Move(Snake.Direction.Right);
                break;
        }
    }

    Console.CursorVisible = true;

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use GOTO statements, its considered bad practice. I would use a while loop with some exit condition that when met exits the loop, for example when the player wins/loses, it exits.

As far as the question goes, it looks like you are just erasing and rewriting the snake head when the player moves the snake. If you wanted it to behave like a traditional snake game, you would have to look at which direction the player moved it, look at all the current locations of the snake's * body parts, then calculate each body part's new position based on which direction the player is moving the snake to. 
You could also just move the snakes head, then the 2nd part of the snakes body will be at the same position the head was just in, the 3rd part will be in the 2nd part's previous position, and so forth and so on until you calculate each body part's position, erasing and writing the new positions as you go along.

You may want to also think about encapsulating some of this logic into a snake class because its going to get messy trying to do it all in a for loop.

After that you can start to tackle more difficult issues like what happens when you move into a wall.